# With Python, get JSON variable from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json

With Python 3.x, I'm trying to get a list of values that are in what looks to be a JSON variable.

Here's some of the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var BandData = {
    id: 171185318,
    name: "MASS",
    fan_email: null,
    account_id: 365569831,
    has_discounts: null,
    image_id: 39000212
};

var EmbedData = {
    tralbum_param: { name: "album", value: 28473799 }, 
    show_campaign: null, 
    embed_info: {"exclusive_embeddable":null,"public_embeddable":"01 Dec 2011 06:09:19 GMT","no_track_preorder":false,"item_public":true}
};

var FanData = {
    logged_in: false,
    name: null,
    image_id: null,
    ip_country_code: null
};

var TralbumData = {
    current: {"require_email_0":1,"new_date":"18 Jan 2017 22:59:06 GMT"},
    is_preorder: null,
    album_is_preorder: null,
    album_release_date: "01 Dec 2017 00:00:00 GMT",
    preorder_count: null,
    hasAudio: true,
    art_id: 3862222,
    trackinfo: [{"video_featured":null,"has_lyrics":false,"file":{"mp3-128":"https://t4.bcbits.com/stream/064bc3d8bb5/mp3-128/35322674"},"is_capped":null,"sizeof_lyrics":0,"duration":143.244,"encodings_id":830008708},{"video_featured":null,"has_lyrics":false,"license_type":0}],
    playing_from: "album page",
    featured_track_id: 8612194,
};
```

Specifically, within `TralbumData`, I'm trying to get the URLs within `mp3-128` within `trackinfo`.

It's tricky for me. It looks like JSON data, but I can't quite get that to work.

So far, I'm able to at least isolate `trackinfo` in the `TralbumData` variable, with a really kludgy function, but can't quite get it from there.  Here's what I have to try and find `trackinfo` and then get the URLs within...:

```
def get_HTML(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    page_source = response.read()
    site_html = page_source.decode('utf8')
    response.close()

    JSON = re.compile('TralbumData = ({.*?});', re.DOTALL)
    matches = JSON.search(site_html)
    info = matches.group(1)
    # print(info)

    data = info.split("\n")
    return data

def get_trackinfo(data):
    # print(data[11])
    for entry in data:
        tmp = entry.split(":")
        if tmp[0].strip() == "trackinfo":
            for ent in tmp:
                tmp = ent.split("mp3-128")
                print(tmp)
```

Doesn't work since it's splitting with `:`, effectively separating the `http://` part.

I'd think there's a way (and I've looked around and the answers to similar questions here on SO get close, but not quite there), to do say `url = my_html['TralbumData']['trackinfo']['mp3-128']` or something.

Comment: How much variation is there in that list? Just decode that line (after `trackinfo:`) as JSON and extract the thing you want from the Python list?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'm almost positive it's always going to have this layout.  And I've been trying to get what you suggest, but am having trouble understanding how to decode the line after trackinfo as JSON.  Right now, I'm futzing around with a bunch of string/list manipulation which is getting unruly and is almost certainly not the most Pythonic way.

Comment: Split into lines, pick the one with `trackerinfo` in it, split on `:` with `str.partition()`, strip, decode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - If I try and split `data` in to lines, with `data.splitlines()`, I can't because the type is incorrect.  My `data` is a list.   I've edited my OP to show you how I'm getting the HTML currently (`get_HTML`).  I've also found that in `get_trackinfo(data)`, if I do `print(data[11])`, I correctly get data starting `trackinfo: [{"video_featured":null, ...`)  but *still* am struggling with how to parse that result...Thanks for your continued help though

Comment: You *already* split it into lines: `info.split("\n")`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - In `get_trackinfo(data)`, I'm trying this:  `info = data[11]` which just returns `trackinfo: [{"video_featured":null, ...}],`.  I'm having trouble going through *that* to get to `"file":{"mp3-128":"https://www.URLIWANT...` to just get the URL of mp3-128 which is within the `file` dictionary.

Comment: I already told you the steps needed from that point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162121/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively straightforward solution using `json`:

```
import re, json, pprint, urllib.request

regex_data = re.compile(r"""
    ^\s*var\s+TralbumData\s*=\s*\{(.*?)^\};
    """, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

regex_item = re.compile(r"""
    ^\s*([\'"]?)([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)\1\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*,?\s*$
    """, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

def scrape(url):
    result = {}
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read().decode('utf8')
    response.close()
    match = regex_data.search(html)
    if match is not None:
        for line in match.group(0).splitlines():
            match = regex_item.match(line)
            if match is None:
                continue
            key, value = match.group(2, 3)
            try:
                result[key] = json.loads(value)
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                pass
    return result

tralbumdata = scrape('https://studiomdhr.bandcamp.com/releases')

pprint.pprint(tralbumdata)
```

This assumes that the layout of `TralbumData` object in the javascript code has each of its top-level `key:value` items on a separate line. It also assumes that all lower-level javascript objects have string keys, as this is required by the [json format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example). (Note that lines ending in a comment cannot be parsed, because json doesn't support comments at all).

Comment: Woah holy cow, thanks!  This works and I can follow most of it.  Does `Match()` find all instances of an item? I.e. if there were say `5` instances of `trackinfo` or `TralbumData`, would match return `4` (I assume it starts with 0) and I could loop through the matches via `group()`?

Comment: Also when if you have a moment, do you mind breaking down the regex match?  I'm trying to make sense of it but am still learning there too.

Comment: Does the `match = regex.search(html)` for some reason stop after the `trackinfo` section? I'm also trying just to pull `featured_track_id` from the JSON but can't quite figure out how. I added a `if re.match(r'featured_track_id`, line)` type part too, but that doesn't seem to grab it. How would I get a value of one of the "top level" variables?

Comment: @BruceWayne. It makes no sense to search for more one `trackinfo` or `TralbumData`, because variables and keys cannot be duplicated. I have now updated the script to parse the entire `TralbumData` object, which is returned as a python `dict`. The regexes are fairly simple. They mostly just allow for variable amounts of whitespace. The `item` regex also allows for optional quotes around the keys (the `\1` is a back-reference to whatever is matched by the first group).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks for the edit! I like how it works now.  Hopefully my last follow up (I really appreciate your help and patience!) is how to get info within that `file:{}` part.  I can do `info = scrape(url)` and then `print(info['current'])` or `print(info[])`, but when I try `print(info['file'])` or `print(info['file']['mp3-128'])` I get an error "KeyError: 'file'"

Comment: @BruceWayne. `info['trackinfo'][0]['file']`, etc. It has exactly the same structure as the javascrip object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:
1. `get_var` function does initial parsing so then you can try to use JSON functions
2. apply `json.loads(var)` and get access to the JSON elements

```
import re
import json

text = """
<script type="text/javascript">

var BandData = {
    id: 171185318,
    name: "MASS",
    fan_email: null,
    account_id: 365569831,
    has_discounts: null,
    image_id: 39000212
};

var EmbedData = {
    tralbum_param: { name: "album", value: 28473799 }, 
    show_campaign: null, 
    embed_info: {"exclusive_embeddable":null,"public_embeddable":"01 Dec 2011 06:09:19 GMT","no_track_preorder":false,"item_public":true}
};

var FanData = {
    logged_in: false,
    name: null,
    image_id: null,
    ip_country_code: null
};

var TralbumData = {
    current: {"require_email_0":1,"new_date":"18 Jan 2017 22:59:06 GMT"},
    is_preorder: null,
    album_is_preorder: null,
    album_release_date: "01 Dec 2017 00:00:00 GMT",
    preorder_count: null,
    hasAudio: true,
    art_id: 3862222,
    trackinfo: [{"video_featured":null,"has_lyrics":false,"file":{"mp3-128":"https://t4.bcbits.com/stream/064bc3d8bb5/mp3-128/35322674"},"is_capped":null,"sizeof_lyrics":0,"duration":143.244,"encodings_id":830008708},{"video_featured":null,"has_lyrics":false,"license_type":0}],
    playing_from: "album page",
    featured_track_id: 8612194,
};
"""

def get_var(text, var):
    """
    :type text: str
    :type var: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    pattern = 'var\s+' + var.rstrip() + '\s+?=\s+?{'
    open_token_found = False
    block = '{'
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        if open_token_found:
            if re.match('};', line):
                block += '}'
                break
            else:
                segments = line.split(':', 1)
                key = segments[0]
                if key[0] != '"':
                    key = '"' + key
                if key[-1] != '"':
                    key = key + '"'
                block += key + ':' + segments[1]
        elif re.match(pattern, line):
                open_token_found = True

    if block[-2] == ',':
        block = block[:-2] + '}'
    return json.loads(block)


var = get_var(text, 'TralbumData')
print(var['trackinfo'][0]['file']['mp3-128'])
```

**Output:**

`https://t4.bcbits.com/stream/064bc3d8bb5/mp3-128/35322674`

Comment: I get an error, `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 32 (char 31)`, with the `return json.loads(block)` line highlighted.

Comment: @BruceWayne I added extended part from the top where I import libraries.

Comment: That's odd, I already have those two libraries importing at the top.  Still getting that error though.  Does it matter that I'm importing a pages *entire* html, not just the snippet I provided? (Trying your way, I tweak `get_HTML` to end with `return site_html`.)

Comment: From looking around, it looks like this error is because it's not in the appropriate JSON format when I get to `.loads()`?